# Is Chronos Kronos?

Tags: greek, titans

Well, I saw a youtube comment on the latest Crash Course Mythology video-

> Chronus has nothing to do with time. That's Kronos, a primordial deity separate from the titans and infinitely more important.
>   Chronus took over the position of Sky God from his father Ouranos, and was later usurped by his own son Zeus who took the same position.
>   I'm sick and tired of people misrepresenting Chronus and Kronos. This is Renaissance era confusion and it needs to stop.

I also see

> No they didn't actually. Kronos (the titan) was spelled Κρόνος whereas Chronos was spelled like Χρόνος, which makes perfect sense since 'chrono-' is used as a root to convey time.

As used in chronological, chronicle, and chronic pain.

So, now I'm confused. Is Chronos Kronos or not? Preferably either using a primary source that says Chronos is the lord of time, or something.

Comment: See http://www.theoi.com/Titan/TitanKronos.html and http://www.theoi.com/Protogenos/Khronos.html

Comment: See my note to C.M.'s answer for the lexicon entries on the two words, which are almost certainly related.  Serious Greek scholars I studied under held this view, and claiming the words (which are identical except for the initial consonant) to be unrelated reveals a lack of understanding of Ancient Greek, imho.

Comment: See *[Cronus: Name and comparative mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus#Name_and_comparative_mythology)*.

Comment: Related now: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/8038/which-specific-ancient-sources-did-not-consider-kronus-and-chronos-to-be-the-sam?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, never get your mythology from Youtube comments.

Second, the second comment is the accurate one. Χ in Greek is transliterated as *ch*, and that's where we get our time words from (as they mention).

I believe the first comment is just confused, where the user once read what the second person is saying, but got it exactly backwards. In both cases they're right in saying that originally *Chronus* and *Cronus* (or Khronos and Kronos, Greek Χρόνος and Κρόνος, "Time" and "Father of Zeus") weren't the same. The first person got it backwards, and the second one got it right.

Comment: Just to support what C.M. explains: [Kronos/Cronus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=kronos&la=greek#lexicon) is used for the personification of time as son of Gaia and Ouranos, where [xronos/chronos](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=xronos&la=greek#Perseus:text:1999.04.0058:entry=xro/nos-contents) is the abstract concept.